# jQuery slider with content not perfectly working

Tags: jquery, slideshow, carousel

I have used the slider 
http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/

Now i need some content with the images in the slider. How can i put the content with the image.

I have the the slide div like

When i wrapped the image with a div and add content to the div, it is not working

I did like the below

```
<div id="carousel">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Test Content</p>
    <img src="img/building1.jpg" alt="building1" width="990" height="450" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Test Content</p>
    <img src="img/building2.jpg" alt="building2" width="990" height="450" />
  </div>
</div>
```

But it was not working. So how can i add the content to the slider.

Comment: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/24/ maybe you can get some info out the source of this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to absolutely position the content you want to appear over the top of the image.

Try this css:

```
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.wrap img {
  display: block;
}
.wrap p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
}
```